# How to import firebase in service worker?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Here is my code. I do not know why I get an error. Here is the part of my code where I want to use it:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.4/firebase.js');

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: xxxxxxxxxxx,
    authDomain: xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    databaseURL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    projectId: xxxxxxxxxxx,
    storageBucket: xxxxxxxxxx,
    messagingSenderId: xxxxxxxxxxxx,
    appId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
  import firebase from 'firebase'

  const config = {
  apiKey: xxxxxxxxxx,
  authDomain: xxxxxxxxxx,
  databaseURL: xxxxxxxxxx,
  projectId: xxxxxxxxxx,
  storageBucket: xxxxxxxxxx,
  messagingSenderId: xxxxxxxxxx
  appId: xxxxxxxxxx
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 firebase.firestore().settings({});
 export default firebase;
```

Comment: It does no wor. That is what i get from my console when i use it:" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 0):

Add web application platform to the firebase console or project from there you find config information and add it in code.